# add all objects with the same key from an NSDictionary to a NSArray

Tags: iphone, nsarray, nsdictionary

```
NSArray *myArray=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userInfo"];

    for(NSDictionary *d in myArray){

        newInfo=[d valueForKey:@"screen_name"];

        NSLog(@"%@", newInfo);      

        listOfTerms=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:newInfo, nil];


        NSLog(@"here   %@", listOfTerms);           
    }
```

above you can see the code i'm using, but listOfTerms only ever has one entry which seems to be the last object in the dictionary. i've been trying to sort this out for some hours now. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Key-Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html), that whole code can be replaced by:

```
NSArray *myArray=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userInfo"];
NSArray *listOfTerms = [myArray valueForKey:@"screen_name"];
```

Know the framework, use it for your advantage.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting listOfTerms in every iteration, try this instead:

```
listOfTerms = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *myArray=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userInfo"];

for(NSDictionary *d in myArray){

    newInfo=[d valueForKey:@"screen_name"];

    NSLog(@"%@", newInfo);      

    [listOfTerms addObject:newInfo];

    NSLog(@"here   %@", listOfTerms);           
}
```

Comment: thank you so much @Nick you have stopped my head from spinning. i was up until 3am trying to figure that stuff out. i knew it was gonna be something simple. thanks again